# Why the VSCode can't find the header file existed in the workspace?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

version: VSCode 1.85.2

OS: win11 with ubuntu 20.04 on wsl 2

I'm doing a MIT 6.S081 Lab, actually the project can be built and has run successfully. But the header files included in some files always show an error line, shown in the picture below.[image]

I have tried to disable all C/C++ extensions and re-enable them. I also have updated the includepath configuration, shown in the picture below , But there are still red curve lines.

[image]

Comment: It might help if you show us the configuration you changed.

Comment: Please always add text information as text, not as pictures.

Comment: If your include folder contains `..../kernel` and you include `kernel/xyz.h` then the actual location needs to be `..../kernel/kernel/xyz.h` which is probably not the case. You should try to remove the `/kernel` part from the include path.

Answer (score 1):

Adding system include path and include paths in the setting file did help me solve this problem.

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
    "${projectPath}\\Drivers\\",
 ]

"C_Cpp.default.systemIncludePath": [
    "C:\\Keil_v5\\ARM\\ARMCLANG\\include",
    "C:\\Keil_v5\\ARM\\ARMCLANG\\include\\libcxx",
    "%LocalAppData%\\Arm\\Packs\\ARM\\CMSIS\\5.9.0\\CMSIS\\RTOS2\\Include",
    "%LocalAppData%\\Arm\\Packs\\ARM\\CMSIS\\5.9.0\\CMSIS\\Core\\Include",
],
```